# I'm trying to flip an animation, but maybe its the rig, my animation just don't flip the way I want it to

Tags: animation, rigging

So don't worry about the animation, basically I just wanna test out how to make flipped animations, but it seems like my rig has something wrong with it, and the animations just don't be flipping the right way I want it to. Please, anyone help?

The Animation(Don't worry about it, just a random pose, I just wanna test the flip out):

[image]

I added a flipped one some frames after it:

[image]

It seems like the animation has got it, the keyframes are somewhat flipping right, it's just some of the axis are acting weird, I'm really new to this animating and rigging thingy, can anyone please help me out? Any suggestions or tips will help too :D

Comment: It may be because some bones have not flipped the pose because they are not named correctly, or because their orientation is bad and in that case you need to roll them in Edit mode (Ctrl R)

Comment: maybe tell what bone doesn't work properly and share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/